# iPad with real GPS

Tags: gps, ipad

Historically, iPads have not had true GPS. The GPS they have goes through a cell phone network, called Assisted GPS. Now I hear that iPads are coming with true GPS. How do I know if a particular iPad has true GPS?

We've ordered [Part number MH312LL/A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OTWXW2I) with Verizon iPad non-SIM Card (HH702LL/A)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood what "assisted GPS" means. The "assisted" part means that the device first uses it's cellphone signal (or wifi) to make a rough estimate as to where it is. It uses this information to reduce the time it takes to get a fix with the regular GPS signal - i.e., the cellphone/wifi *assists* the GPS. Without this assistance it can take much longer to get a lock.

Both types of iPad can use location-based services, but only the device with a SIM card has an actual GPS module. The wifi-only device can take a guess at where it is, based on the wifi SSIDs it can see - Apple knows where these are, from other users devices that also had a GPS and reported it previously - or by using a database similar to http://www.hostip.info/

http://gps.about.com/od/accessories/a/New-Ipad-Gps.htm

Answer (score 2):

> GPS is available on iPhone and iPad Wi-Fi + Cellular models

This is a footnote for Global Positioning System (GPS) networks on the Apple Support pages for Location Services...

- iOS 8: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033
- iOS 7: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201357

This page for a Marine Navigation product makes consistent statements, including some clarification of the difference between 'Assisted GPS' and 'True GPS':

- http://www.seaiq.com/p/choosing-ipad.html

And there is some interesting discussion on iFixit:

- https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/148307/Is+there+a+GPS+in+the+iPad+air

Comment: This particular iPad has iOS 8. Looking at the  iOS 8 documentation you pointed I see nothing that says the the iPad has true GPS. I'm looking for something saying `GPS Chipset` or the like. It says that GPS comes an iPads with cellular + wifi, but not with just wifi, which is suspicious. The ifixit forum does say that it is true GPS.